# Safari not handling html5 video events properly?

Tags: javascript, html, video, safari

I'm working on a project which uses a cookie to save the user's progress on an html5 video, so they can pick up where they left off on subsequent visits.

The problem is that none of the HTML5 video events seem to be firing properly, on Safari only. All other browsers work fine.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    updateVideoProgress();
    var interval = setInterval(function() {storeVideoProgress()}, 1000);
}, false);

if (video.readyState > 3) {
    updateVideoProgress();
    var interval = setInterval(function() {storeVideoProgress()}, 1000);
}
```

Note that it doesn't matter what event I'm listening for. I've tried "loadeddata", "canplay", "canplaythrough", etc., and none of them are firing on Safari. On every other browser, all these events fire (but depending on the event may compromise the functionality of my code).

TL:DR -- Has anyone ever experienced Safari not firing HTML5 video events, while all other browsers handle them fine? What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

`canplay` event will work for chrome and firefox. I just treat `loadedmetadat` as an iOS specific `canplay` event as iOS does not seem to trigger `canplay` on its own.

Video plays fine once I replicated my `canplay` logic in `loadedmetadata`.